# Adding a count function to column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting to add a count function in a separate column to the dv.severity column name. The column includes the output of severity: moderate and critical. The following is my current query which works.

```
SELECT ds.name AS site, date_published, dv.severity, dv.title AS vulnerability_title
FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding favf, dv.severity
   JOIN dim_asset da USING (asset_id) 
   JOIN dim_operating_system dos USING (operating_system_id) 
   JOIN dim_vulnerability dv USING (vulnerability_id) 
   JOIN dim_site_asset dsa USING (asset_id) 
   JOIN dim_site ds USING (site_id) 
WHERE now() - date_published < INTERVAL '180 days'
ORDER BY dv.title ASC
```

The following is a snippet from my output

```
+ --------+----------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| site    | date_published | severity | vulnarability_title                                             |
+ --------+----------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| MEAS-de | 1/30/2018      | Severe   | 7-Zip: CVE-2017-17969: Heap based buffer overflow vulnarability |
+ --------+----------------+----------+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Result Now: 4 Columns; Site, date_published, severity, vulnerability_title

Result I would like 5 Columns; Site, date_published, severity, severity_count, vulnerability_title

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Could you please [edit] your question to make it a bit more understandable? See [ask] for information on how to properly ask a question. Please give us some sample data and the expected output. Tell us your [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Database_management_systems) as well since answers may be different for each DBMS. Help us help you!

Comment: What's the specific database engine?

Comment: Over what data would like to add a count? When counting a specific amount of rows that meet a specific condition a `GROUP BY`  clause is mandatory. See information about the `count()` function on `Postgressql` [here](https://www.techonthenet.com/postgresql/functions/count.php)

Comment: So how does your result look now and how do you want it to look like instead? Show some sample rows.

Comment: I am looking to add a count to the three areas: Severity, moderate and critical. However the statement "dv.severity" when ran outputs those three areas of severity, moderate and critical. So i presume my query should include the GROUP BY at the end of the statement under last JOIN? Hope I answered the question.

Comment: I've edited your request to include the information you mistakenly put into an "answer". I also replaced the image with text, for this helps us better help you. However, I don't understand the count column you are looking for. You should have shown more sample rows and also shown rows for the requested result. You can edit your request to do this now. Do you get duplicate rows for Site, date_published, severity, vulnerability_title? Do you want to replace, say, four rows with the same combination of Site, date_published, severity, vulnerability_title with one row and the count 4?

Comment: Or do you want to keep the rows you have and only count how often 'Severe' occurs in them and display this number next to every 'Severe'? (And do the same for the other severities of course.)

Comment: `FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding favf, dv.severity` is a typo, correct? IT's only `FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding favf`, yes?

Comment: My current report show the following information: SITE: Column is a listing of all the sites in our database. DATE_PUBLISHED: Column shows what date the CVE was published on. SEVERITY: Column tells whither the CVE is a severe, moderate or critical rating. VULNERABILITY_TITLE: Column defines what the CVE is (ex: security update for flash player) The query is from a vulnerability scanner. My final goal is to get a count of the following severity, critical and moderate.

Answer (score 0):

Thorsten: The following is a snippet from my output

[image]

***Result Now:*** 4 Columns; Site, date_published, severity, vulnerability_title

Result I would like
5 Columns; Site, date_published, severity, severity_count, vulnerability_title

Comment: Please do not post additional information as an answer. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52480870/edit) your question by clicking on the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52480870/edit) link right below your question.

Answer (score 0):

FROM fact_asset_vulnerability_finding favf, dv.severity --- is not a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the count. I need to add the following: count(dv.severity) and GROUP BY site, date_published, severity, vulnerability_title. This allowed me the ability to have a count function.